# add header at top in csv file of append blob

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, azure-logic-apps, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-data-factory

I am  creating a pipeline in Azure data factory where I am using Function app as one of activity to transform data and store in append blob container as csv format .As I have taken 50 batches in for loop so 50 times my function app is to process data for each order.I am appending header in csv file with below logic.

//First I am creating file as per business logic //
//csveventcontent is my source data //

```
            var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            string FileDate = dateAndTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
            string FileName = _config.ContainerName + FileDate + ".csv";
            StringBuilder csveventcontent = new StringBuilder();
            OrderEventService obj = new OrderEventService();
```

//Now I am checking if todays file exists and if it doesn't we create it.//

```
               if (await appBlob.ExistsAsync() == false)

            {
               await appBlob.CreateOrReplaceAsync(); //CreateOrReplace(); 
              //Append Header
                csveventcontent.AppendLine(obj.GetHeader());
            }
```

Now the problem is header is appending so many times in csv file .Sometimes it is not appending at top.Probably due to parralel function app is running 50 times.

How I can fixed header at top only at one time.
I have tried with data flow and logic app also but unable to do it.If it can be handled through code that would be easier I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right there. Its the concurrency of the function app that is causing the problem. The best approach would be to use a queue and process messages one by one. Or you could use a distributed lock to ensure only one function writes to the file at a time. You can use blob leases for this.

The Lease Blob operation creates and manages a lock on a blob for write and delete operations. The lock duration can be 15 to 60 seconds, or can be infinite.

Refer: [Lease Blob Request Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob)